# yii2 include html code inside Html::button

Tags: yii2

I need to include some html code inside Html::button in yii2. According to the [Class yii\helpers\BaseHtml](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#button%28%29-detail)  i can pass html code to $content. Please, correct me if i am wrong. So i wrote:

```
<?= Html::button{'<div class=\'row\'></div>,[]); ?>
```

and it works. But what if the code i want to insert is big? How do i include big code with less pain?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use views and [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial%28%29-detail)

e.g. in your view

```
 <?php
 $html = $this->context->renderPartial('sub_view', [
        'attribute' => 'test',
 ]);
 echo Html::button($html,[]);
 ?>
```

and in your subview your static html or dynamic code

```
 <h1>static html code<h1>
 <div>
 <?php 
   echo $attribute
 ?>
 </div>
```